# Коннект к SQL Server из PHP скрипта с хостинга

Tags: tcp-ip, php, sql-server

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь соединиться PHP скриптом (лежит на хостинге) к компьютеру с SQL Server.
Проблема заключается в том, что ПК сети через роутер по ADSL выходят в инет под одним статическим IP.
Как в этом случае производить коннект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо на роутере настроить так называемый проброс портов. В DLink, например, этот раздел называется Port Mapping. Указывается порт, и айпи компьютера во внутренней сети, куда нужно перебросить соединение. У MySQL по умолчанию порт 3306

Comment: Т.е. если например настроить роутер на проброс порта 1433 для ПК1 с лок адресом, например, 192.168.1.77, то если я буду обращаться из вне на адрес 123.123.123.123,1433 - это будет ПК1?

Comment: Да, именно так. При этом порты не обязательно должны совпадать. Можно, к примеру, настроить форвардинг с 123.123.123.123:14331 на 192.168.1.77:1433, с 123.123.123.123:14332 на 192.168.1.78:1433, и т.д.

Comment: да, именно так

Answer (score 1):

Брать внешний IP дл компа с сервером либо перенастраивать роутер

Comment: Внешний IP у всех компов один.

Comment: А я говорю, надо брать отдельный внешний IP для сервера =) У многих провайдеров такая услуга есть, часто платная. Как раз в т.ч. для ваших целей.