# Удалённое подключение к SQL Server из SSMS

Tags: windows, tcp-ip, sql-server

Добрый день.Уже спрашивал про [удалённое подключение к MSSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19178/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BA-sql-server-%D0%B8%D0%B7-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0), где посоветовали настроить на роутере проброс порта. Админ мне настроил проброс для порта 25170. В Менеджере Конфигураций SQL Server в Клиентских протоколах в TCP/IP выставил порт 25170, в брандмауэре винды создал правила для этого порта(TCP и UDP). В SSMS с второго компьютера коннекчусь к целевому SQL Server1`у: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,25170\ИмяПКнаКоторомСтоитЦелевойSQLServer. В ответ: ...произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определённым экземпляром...ошибка:10060.Что я неправильно сконфигурировал или неправильно подключаюсь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А это формат адреса такой? Ведь если вы все настроили это уже прямое подключение к серверу, соответственно ИмяПК ему уже и не нужно. Т.е. по умолчанию, админская настройка шлет все с порта 25170 внешнего ПК на порт 25170 внутреннего.

Comment: Я по разному пробовал прописывать адрес в строке подключения к серверу, но безуспешно. Значит я сконфигурировал что то неправильно, но что я не знаю, подскажите?!

Comment: Проверить бы открыт ли ваш порт. Попробуйте проверить http://2ip.ru/check-port/Загляните еще сюда http://www.npo-comp.ru/faq/faq_3219555.shtml

Comment: Порт открыт, я проверял. Нюанс в том, что все пк через роутер выходят под одним IP. Админ настроил проброс на порт 25170 для ПК с SQL Server. Так что если проверять порт (http://2ip.ru/check-port/) он будет "Порт открыт" для всех компьютеров из моей локальной сети.Сейчас ещё почитаю статью, что скинули, надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Прочитал, но не нашён в __"Настройке контактной зоны для служб и соединений", в группе настроек Database Engine выбрать "Удаленные соединения" и указать протокол, по которому разрешается удаленное подключение."__. Ещё нет файла __sqlservr.exe__ в C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\, где MSSQL.1 - идентификатор экземпляра SQL сервера